# wpf media element does not play video on first button click

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I have a WPF application with a mediaelement control to for video play. It is 2GB MJPEG encodered, avi container video. After doing some little research (Googling) I found that I need to check that the media element has the time span of the video before i can actually play it. When the user clicks the button play for the first time; the video does not play, but after clicking the button three times, then it plays.

```
private void playPauseVideoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tag == "1")
    {
        flagFrameCapture = false;               //if video is playing then no need to allow user capture anything
        fOnly = false;
        fullFrameRadioButton.IsChecked = false;
        countClickFrameCapture = 0;             //assign 0 to use it as a flag to determine if the frame has been saved or not
        playPauseVideoButton.Tag = "2";         //determines if the video is paused or playing
        saveButton.IsEnabled = false;           //disable button save
        DisableRadioButtons();                  //disable the radio button
        flagRectangle = false;                  //flag that we are playing a video
        flagEllipse = false;
        CapturedFullImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; //make Image component invisible
        //RemovePins();
        //LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible = !LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible;

        //LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible = !LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible;

        if (playVideoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)              //check that the video has not reached the end
        {
            playVideoMediaElement.Play();               //play the video
            InitialiseSliderAndTimer();                                           //default the video slider and timer
            ChangePlayPauseButtonImageIcon();           //changes the image icon of the button to pause icon
            IsPlaying(true);                            //method enables or disables the buttons
            IsPaused(true);                             //enable the fast and slow palay buttons
        }
    }
}
```

does anyone know why this is?